# UITableView space between section and its header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView` with 2 sections and i preserve a specific width for each section header as follows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (section==0) {
    return 45;
}
if (section==1) {
    return 20;
}

return 0;

}
```

also here's `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:15];
lbl.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
lbl.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
lbl.alpha = 0.9;
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

if(section == 0){
    lbl.text =[LocalizationSystem get:@"Share_Today_times" alter:@""];
}
if(section == 1){
    lbl.text =[LocalizationSystem get:@"Share_Month_Times" alter:@""];
}

return lbl;

}
```

the problem is that there's a space between the first section and its header which doesn't exist in the other sections, as you see in the image below the second section has no space between its header which appears apparently in the first section (the region with the black dots), does any one know how to solve these issue? thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You most probably have problems with offsets in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method

Comment: an edit have been made

Comment: Why do you have 45 for your first section, your label is probably at the top of that section.

Comment: if i removed 45 the label won't appears, it will go up!!

Comment: You're not setting neither frame nor constraints for your labels. Have you tried initializing them with frame?

Comment: no but if i removed 45 the label won't appear at all !!

Comment: 45 - you're talking about a different method. Try initializing your lbl with a frame 0, 0, tableview.frame.size.width, 45

Comment: You mean remove the whole condition (section == 0) or replace it with 20 like (section == 1) ? Eugene is right you need to set your label's frame, your label going up is a different issue.

Comment: yes i mean to remove the whole condition, i tried to init the label with a frame 0, 0, tableview.frame.size.width, 45 but nothing changes !! the space remains

Comment: Have you set a grouped table view ? are you sure its frame starts after the top bar?

Comment: yes its a grouped table view and its frame starts after the top bar

Comment: I've tried your code, the space is caused by the 45. 
The label is centered vertically in its header view. The only reason it could go up is that your tableview frame is not correctly defined. Try adding NSLog(@"%f",tableView.frame.origin.y);

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing your `heightForHeaderInSection` method's implementation to

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 20;
}
```

The reason might be that `Share Today Prayers Time` section has index 0 and you set height of 45 pixels to it, when the next section has index 1 and height of 20, which is apparently not what you want.